# Why doesn't Javascript's language design include waiting for variables to resolve before using them?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

In Javascript, you need to tell your code explicitly to wait for a variable to resolve before using it with the `await` keyword, like so:

```
let x = await doSomethingAsynchronous()
console.log(`The result is ${x.result}`)
```

If "await" is not specifically included, Javascript will happily try to access `x.result` before `x` has been resolved, and hence throw an error. Why is this the default? How often do programmers want to use a variable before it is resolved? Why doesn't the Javascript compiler insert an `await` directly before an unresolved variable is used?

I am quite new to Javascript so sorry if the answer is obvious and thanks in advance for your help.

Footnotes -

1. By 'used' I mean accessed in some way (eg `x.result`), not just passed to another function, in which case resolution is of course not immediately needed.
2. I can see that having the `await` keyword available in the language syntax is useful in case the programmer wants to invoke it explicitly, for example, when the variable to be resolved is not yet being used, but the next line depends on some side effect of `doSomethingAsynchronous` having been completed. So I am not asking why it exists in the language syntax, just why it isn't inserted by default.

Comment: the return value of `doSomethingAsynchronous` is a `Promise`. `await` just helps unpack that.

Comment: What if you want to do something with the promise returned from `doSomethingAsynchronous`?

Comment: There is no such thing as an unresolved variable. `doSomethingAsynchronous( )` probably returns a Promise that may already be rejected or resolved, or may still be pending. If you leave off the await then `x` will be a reference to that Promise instead of whatever value that Promise resolves with. There's all kinds of things you might want to do with that Promise.

Comment: I'd rather have more control than less.

Comment: I order a pizza online, why doesn't it just show up right away? That is how asynchronous things work.

Comment: Why doesn't it, because not everything needs to be synchronous. Come join the fun before the world of await and promises. Call back hell was a fun time.

Comment: @epascarello I think you misunderstand the question. He's just asking why `await` is explicit instead of implicit. It would be perfectly possible to have an implicit await in a language that would still be asynchronous. If the language designers wanted to make Promises (and any object for that matter) awkward to work with they could've made `x.result` behave the same as `(await x).result`, although it's not clear how you would access a property of the Promise itself, like `x.then` in that case.

Comment: @epascarello the question is quite on point, the OP seems to understand asynchronity. Not sure why your comment gets 3 upvotes although it is missing the point (just as the seven downvotes, whats wrong with you all)

Comment: If you want compile time checks on `x.Result`, you might want to use [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Comment: Sometimes you have a call that it doesn't need something in return, say a update to a database, where other times you need something returned. So there's why await is not implicit ^  ^  Oh and it's not the variable that it's resolved, it's the asynchronous call!

Comment: @JonasWilms The OP wants to know why something is not set by default. The answer is "because it is not".... I am not sure what OP is expecting. And a change like that would be "BREAKING"

Comment: @epascarello no, `await` was only introduced with `async function`s, They could've introduced other keywords as well. "The answer is 'because it is not'..." well as an experienced developer one can at least make some educated guesses, nevertheless your comment is still missing the point. There is a `delete` button next to comments in case they are unappropriate

Comment: @JonasWilms I will leave it.

Comment: @epascarello I explained what the OP is really asking...

Answer (score 1):

> How often do programmers want to use a variable before it is resolved?

Quite rarely actually. I can only remember one case where I commented out await, it was something like:

```
 const result = await database();

 if(check)
   /*await*/ notifyUser();

 return result;
```

I needed it in that case as I don't mind if the notification arrives after the response gets returned. And I still left the comment there to make sure that future readers get the asynchronity. So yes, if there would be the opposite keyword, I (and others) would save a lot of typing.

> [Then] why is this [not awaiting the] default?

I can only see two reasons:

If awaiting would be implicit, you can't tell from the code how it will behave, a function call might cause the functions execution to halt and you get unexpected execution order (hard to debug = bad):

```
async function stuff() {
 a();
 console.log("a");
 b();
 console.log("b");
}

stuff(); stuff(); // a, a, b, b ... what the ... ?
```

Using `await` is explicit, you know where the `async function` might halt.

Additionally the engine would have to check the response of every function call and every method call on wether it returns a promise:

```
 promise() // await this?
  .then(/*...*/); // or this?
 maybe(); // or this?
```

As JavaScript is a very dynamic language, a function that usually returns a number might suddenly return a Promise, so the engine would have to check every call for a promise, and that's a lot of overhead, and it will be hard to optimize. With `await` the engine doesn't have to check, it will only wait where you told it to wait, which allows for much better optimizations.

However I'm not part of the ES Comitee, to get the definite answer ask them, I can only speculate about their reasons.

Comment: thankyou for your thoughtful answer. I think you have a good point about the compiler having to work harder if it needs to note where each variable is next used, and do an `await` just before that point.


However, I do think the execution order in your example would be totally as expected, as long as you understood that the code `await`ed when a variable got used:

```
async function stuff() {
 a();
 console.log("a"); \\ a is used here, so we wait til it is computed.
 b();
 console.log("b"); \\ b is used here, so we wait til it is computed.
}
stuff(); stuff(); // a, b, a, b
```

Comment: @john how do you know that `a` is async? Maybe just `b` is async ... ?

Comment: hm yes I see your point. Because `b` is only used within `stuff`, not by your top level code, the top level won't wait for `b` to be computed before running `stuff` again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main reasons I can think of:

2) `doSomethingAsynchronous()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and it is perfectly valid and common to want to do something with that Promise other than `await` it.

Here is one example:

```
const promises = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
  promises.push( doSomethingAsynchronous( ) );
const results = await Promise.all( promises );
```

That will start all 100 asynchronous tasks at once and only await at the end; very different from having `await` inside the loop which would await each Promise before starting the next task.

In fact Promises have been around for a while longer than async/await and implicitly awaiting those promises would break a lot of existing code. Because JavaScript is used in web browsers they are very strict about not breaking backwards compatibility.

2) It would make reading/writing JavaScript much more difficult. Consider the following code:

```
setTimeout( function ( ) { console.log( 'FOO' ) }, 0 );
console.log( x.result );
```

Because JavaScript runs code to completion before the event loop continues, it is clear that `console.log( x.result );` runs first before `console.log( 'FOO' );`. If JavaScript had implicit `await` you would not know whether `x.result` is synchronous or not and that would mean the order of those logs would become non-deterministic. In general knowing the order that your code will run in is very important and not being able to tell if the order is well-defined or not would make programming in JavaScript very difficult.

Here is an example:

```js
(async _ => {

  const x = new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( _ => resolve( { foo: 'bar' } ), 1000 ) );
  setTimeout( function ( ) { console.log( '2) async' ) }, 0 );
  x.foo;
  console.log( '1) Sync' );

})();
```

Because `x.foo` is a synchronous operation  (accessing the `foo` property of a Promise will just be undefined, but that's just for demonstration, bear with me) the order of the logs is as expected, but if there was an implicit await in that code (which we can simulate with `(await x)`:

```js
(async _ => {

  const x = new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( _ => resolve( { foo: 'bar' } ), 1000 ) );
  setTimeout( function ( ) { console.log( '2) async' ) }, 0 );
  (await x).foo; // Simulate implicit await
  console.log( '1) Sync??' ); 

})();
```

The logs happen in the opposite order (or potential a non-deterministic order for shorter timers).

You would also not be able to know whether `x.result` can throw an error just by looking at it. You would need to see where `x` is defined to check if it's a Promise (awaiting a Promise throws an error if the Promise is rejected) to know that the line could throw.

Comment: I don't get point 1. What if there would be a `no-await` keyword: `result.push(no-await asyncStuff())` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms That would break code that already works. Promises are older than async/await and `result.push(asyncStuff())` was working code before async/await. Having to modify old code to have it continue working is something the ES team always avoids because of the amount of old, but working code on the web that would break in new browsers. (IE. any BC breaking changes made so far only apply to code that uses "use strict" to avoid breaking existing code, one day they might need a "use stricter" to avoid breaking code that uses "use strict" when they want to make more BC breaking changes).

Comment: well it could be scoped to `async function`s though, then it wouldn't break anything (although it might be even more confusing than a not-`await`ed promise)

Comment: @JonasWilms That's true they could've made all Promise's auto await inside an async function, but that has the issues in point 2. The way they did it was nice because converting existing code meant you could just put `async` in front of all functions that return Promises without breaking anything and then you could slowly change your code from using `Promise.then` everywhere to using await.

Comment: @Paulpro and @JonasWilms thanks for your excellent and thoughtful answers. I see your point that it might be for backwards compatibility, which is more important than new and clever tinkering for a language as widely used as javascript. However I am not sure i agree with your `const results = await Promise.all( promises)` example. Presumably you want to await all these promises before continuing because you need to use all the results. But in my hypothetical, the act of using all the results would automatically cause them all to be awaited, so `await Promise.all` would be done for you.